# Front-end file upload - no error when file exceeds upload_max_filesize

Tags: upload

We have a couple of public profiles that include file fields for users to upload images.

Our php.ini upload_max_filesize is set to 4 MB, and people with files that exceed this, submit the form and receive a positive "Thank you. Your information has been saved." message, but the file is not actually saved. (And a previous file in that field is not overwritten.)

Is there a way I can have Civi give a helpful (i.e. accurate!) response in this case, or is it a CMS thing (Joomla 3.7.5), or is this a Civi limitation/bug that would be good to report on Jira?